# Can I print fetch API data with only use of one then?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Like this

```
fetch(signup_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: user_name.value,
            email: usr_email.value,
            password: usr_password.value,
            username: user_name.value,
            lastname: usr_last_name.value,
            type: usr_type.value,
            phone: ph_number.value
        })
    })
    .then((res) => {
        var data = res.json() //Promise
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Comment: What's exactly is your bug and where is your code?

Comment: either chain promises like: `fetch(...).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));`

Comment: or use `async/await`: `let res = await fetch(...);   let data = await res.json();   console.log(data);`

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Using only `await` is definitely cleaner than mixing Promise-style and await-style, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to await the async function:

```
 fetch(signup_url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            name: user_name.value,
            email: usr_email.value,
            password: usr_password.value,
            username: user_name.value,
            lastname: usr_last_name.value,
            type: usr_type.value,
            phone: ph_number.value
        })
    })
    .then(async (res) => {
        var data = await res.json()
        console.log(data)
    })
```

Though i don't get why you want to use just 1 then.

Comment: You can change the comment to `// resolved Promise`, since it's being awaited.

Comment: Or remove it XD